# How to delete this in C++ class (so that it doesn't enter infinte loop)

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++17, doubly-linked-list

- I have poorly implemented a doubly linked list and I ran into to an
  issue of memory leak.
- The biggest issue it that i need to delete the
  node which I dynamically allocated memory to in heap.
- It enter a infinite loop whenever remove function of double_linked_list class is
  called.
- I tried debugging but it did'nt work.

```
class double_node{
public:
    // Data members
    ll data;
    double_node * next;
    double_node * prev;

    // Functions
    double_node(){
        this->next = nullptr;
        this->prev = nullptr;
        this->data = LLONG_MIN;
    }

    double_node(ll data, double_node * next, double_node * prev){
        this->data = data;
        this->next = next;
        this->prev = prev;
    }

    // WARNING : Memory Leak
    // I don't know why defining a destructor gives an error
     ~double_node(){
         cerr << "~double_node() is called\n";
          if(this != nullptr){
              delete this;
          }
     }
};

class double_linked_list{
public:
    double_node * head = new double_node;
    double_node * tail = new double_node;

    double_linked_list(){
        // Head part
        head->data = LLONG_MIN;
        head->next = tail;
        head->prev = nullptr;
        // Tail part
        tail->data = LLONG_MIN;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        tail->prev = head;
        
    }
    void append(ll data){
        if(head->data == LLONG_MIN){
            head->data = data;
        }
        else if(tail->data == LLONG_MIN){
            tail->data = data;
        }
        else{
            double_node * temp = tail;
            double_node * last = new double_node;
            
            // Setting up last
            last->data = data;

            temp->next = last;
            last->prev = temp;
            last->next = nullptr;

            tail = last;
        }
        
    }

    void remove(ll data){
        double_node * temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr and temp->data != data){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if(temp->data == data){
            double_node * y = temp->prev;
            double_node * x = temp;
            double_node * z = temp->next;
            if (z != nullptr){
                z->prev = y;
            }
            if(y != nullptr){
                y->next = z;
            }
            if(x == head){
                head = z;
            }
            if(temp != nullptr){
                x->next = nullptr;
                x->prev = nullptr;
                delete x;
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `ll data;` -- what is `ll`?  Don't copy bad coding habits from competitive coding websites.  The type you want to use is `int64_t`, not `ll`.  And then `this->data = LLONG_MIN;` --> `data = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();`

Comment: Don't `delete this;` *in the destructor*. In the destructor, the object is already being destroyed.

Comment: Debugging is a critical skill to help one validate and improve one's code. Set breakpoints, step through the code, and watch what happens.

Comment: best is learn more about ownership and reimplement linkedlist. you should delete a data from owner so don't use delete this ( in destructor) in data.

Comment: Are you allowed to use smart pointers?

Comment: `if(this != nullptr){` -- This right there is a bug.  The compiler can totally eliminate this code, since `this` can never be `nullptr`.

Comment: If you can use smart pointers, use them. They help massively in memory leak problems to do with trees, linked lists, etc. etc.

Comment: what happens when you call `delete this`? What function does that call? Think about this and you'll see why you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Assuming the current object was created with the relevant `new` expression, `delete this` (among other things) calls the destructor of the current object i.e. of `*this`. Doing that in a destructor therefore ALWAYS gives an infinite loop, since `delete this` also does not set `this` to be `nullptr` (in fact, it doesn't change the value of `this` at all).   The only way to avoid such an infinite loop is to NEVER `delete this` in a destructor (and, in a destructor body, the object `*this` is already being destroyed, so no need for the destructor to explicitly destroy it again).

Comment: The fact that `double_linked_list`'s `head` and `tail` are different unrelated nodes seems like an error.

Answer (score 4):

> How to delete this in C++ class (so that it doesn't enter infinte loop)

By not deleting `this`. Never do that in a destructor. And there's hardly ever a reason to do that in any function.

Just remove `~double_node` entirely. The node doesn't own any resources, so it doesn't need a user defined destructor.

> I ran into to an issue of memory leak.

You'll need to define `~double_linked_list` that loops over the nodes and deletes them. You will also need to follow [the rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete this` here is recursively calling itself.

```
 ~double_node(){
     cerr << "~double_node() is called\n";
      if(this != nullptr){
          delete this;
      }
 }
```

You can just remove this destructor.

As described in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/

> An expression with the delete operator, first calls the appropriate
> destructor (for class types), and then calls a deallocation function.

You can use `delete this` in some cases, but you should know what you're doing. Here are some tips about this:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this

Additionally, you should check if temp is null after you exit the `while` loop in the remove function. Otherwise it will segfault when trying to remove something it can't find.